# How can I reference a jar that is in lib folder to "java -jar"?

Tags: java

I need to reference the file `procyon-0.6.0.jar` that is inside `libs` folder. I need to execute the command `java -jar libs/procyon-0.6.0 --arguments` but:

- It works if I execute the project from IntelliJ IDEA
- It doesn't works if I execute the built Jar (Gradle) because it cannot find `libs/procyon-0.6.0`

My project structure looks like this:

```
libs
\> procyon-0.6.0.jar

src
\> main
   \> java
      \> me.synnk.jd
         \> Main.java
```

I don't want to use any of the `libs/procyon-0.6.0.jar` classes, I just want to reference it to be used on `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ")` command.

I don't want to use any additional "java -jar Main.java" arguments, no classpath or -cp. Only the common executing method.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Comment: Whether or not it works depends on what the current working directory is. When you execute for IntelliJ, this seems to be the root of your project, but when you run from Gradle, it is probably the build output directory from Gradle, which doesn't contain your `libs` directory. Either modify your Gradle script so the lib directory and its contents are copied to the right location, or use some form of configuration (e.g. using absolute paths) to locate the right directory.

Comment: At start you may extract the lib to a temp folder. I would put the lib into resources and  access direct from Java.

Comment: You got the point @MarkRotteveel, when I ran the gradle's built Jar, it doesn't finds the `libs` directory, but how can I do the `libs` directory and the file get copied to the build folder or put the "procyon.jar" file inside the built jar? so I can send it to my friends and they don't need to download procyon.jar, because it would be already inside the jar.